# PHP ImageMagic unicode characters

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagettftext

```
  perl -e 'binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8"); \
    print "\x{201C}Unicode \x{2018}\x{263A}\x{2019} Please\x{201D}";' |\
      convert -background lightblue -fill blue -pointsize 36 \
              label:@-  label_unifun.gif
```

I am trying to follow ImageMagick documentation to achieve the same result in PHP. However, so far with no result. This is what I have:

```
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setTextEncoding('UTF-8');
$draw->setFontSize(52);

$draw->setFont("font.otf");
$draw->setStrokeAntialias(TRUE);
$draw->setTextAntialias(TRUE);
$draw->annotation(20, 50, "\x{201C}Unicode \x{2018}\x{263A}\x{2019} Please\x{201D}");

$canvas = new Imagick();
$canvas->newImage(1000, 500, "red");
$canvas->drawImage($draw);
$canvas->setImageFormat('png');

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $canvas;
```

But it just prints `\x{201C}Unicode \x{2018}\x{263A}\x{2019} Please\x{201D}`.

Comment: Not an answer but a workaround: have you why don't you use GD2 functions instead of ImageMagick?

Comment: @timdream: GD is worst in every aspect than ImageMagick

Comment: @timdream: I have tried and it did not manage to print some unicode characters.

Comment: @Moore: Could you pint out the difference?

Comment: I've been using GD2 for unicode characters. Make sure your string is in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP will do the escaping for you when passing it to ImageMagick, just insert your Unicode characters un-escaped into your string:

```
$draw->annotation(20, 50, "ééèeèeèaèèèààaàaàaààêêêçcçcçc");
```

Comment: I am not able so far to convert some hex into characters, e.g., `0x2212` which supposed to be a long dash.

Answer (score 0):

I use the command line tool and accept the caption / label from an intermediate file which is created using file_put_contents() to support UNICODE characters.

```
file_put_contents($textFilename, $text);

$cmd = "convert -size ".WIDTH."x".HEIGHT."  -background ".BACKGROUND_COLOR_TTI." -fill ".TEXT_COLOR_TTI." -pointsize ".FONT_SIZE_TTI." -gravity     center    caption:@".$textFilename." ".$newFileName;
```